# Is there another solutions instead of nested Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Now my code is about `Nested RecyclerView` for 3 layer example

- `RecyclerView` of Product have
- `RecyclerView` of comment and order inside and both also have
- `RecyclerView` of reply|COMMENT in comment and order too.

The customer wants this.

Is there another solutions to handle this with good performance.

While I'm using Nested `RecyclerView` it lags and slow if a lot of product, comment, order and reply to display

Comment: Other than performance, I guess nested recyclerview are not good in terms of UX, what you can do is redirect the comment to another dialog or activity, and render the comments recyclerview there.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Piyush "While I'm using Nested RecyclerView it lags and slow if a lot of product, comment, order and reply to display"

Answer (score 3):

Nested Recyclerviews are a bad practice in the material design or google app design guidelines. You will have trouble with a bad and wrong scroll behaviour, it is simply not possible to work with this fluently as a user. Also your views will not be recycled and if your content grows the app will act very slow! There are workarounds but it is all a bad practice and more a bad design. You should inform your customers because there are not aware of those design failures and the technical bottlenecks.

A better way would be to enable to collapse the nested views. And just scroll the whole view or to use paging inside all nested views.

Comment: "use paging inside all nested views" best solution that I can do for now. I can't fight with the customer. They also ask me for the another way of handle list of data too. So. pagination is the answer.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this cool library https://github.com/lisawray/groupie you can find implementation details here https://medium.com/@pedrocarrillo/comments-in-a-recylcerview-e7537235cd33